Splitting the set of primes dividing an integer polynomial
Let $f \in \mathbf{Z}[x]$ and let $\mathbb{P}$ denote the set of positive integer primes.
Let $\mathcal{P}(f)$ denote the set of primes $p$ which solve $f(n) \equiv 0 \text{ (mod } p)$ for some $n \in \mathbf{Z}$.
Let $\mathbb{P}_{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_t \text{ (mod } b)} = \{p \in \mathbb{P} : p \equiv a_1, a_2, \cdots, \text{ or } a_t \text{ (mod } b) \} $.
Question:
Can $\mathcal{P}(f)$ always be expressed as,
$$\mathcal{P}(f) = \mathbb{P}_{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_t \text{ (mod } b)}$$
for some integer $t$?
Here are some examples of such expressions:
$$\mathcal{P}(n^2 + 1) = \mathbb{P}_{1, 2 \text{ (mod } 4)}$$
$$\mathcal{P}(n^2 + n + 1) = \mathbb{P}_{0, 1 \text{ (mod } 3)}$$
$$\mathcal{P}(n^2 + 3n + 1) = \mathbb{P}_{0,1,4 \text{ (mod } 5)}$$
Apologies if this is a well-known result.
Edit:
It seems that the answer is almost certainly no, with a likely counterexample being $f(n) = n^3 - 2$. Then an offshoot question: is it known for which $f$ such a split exists? Are there counterexamples with $\deg(f) = 2$?

no.  take $f(n) = n^3 - 2$  I will need to check primes $2,3$ again...  Otherwise,  this has a single root $\pmod p$  for $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3.$ And three roots for any $p = u^2 + 27 v^2$ But no roots for $p =  4 u^2 + 2 uv + 7 v^2  .$  Together, these account for all primes $1 \pmod 3$

I'm not sure I follow why this means the answer is no. If I understand correctly, you're saying $\mathcal{P}(f) \neq \mathbb{P}_{0, 1, 2 \text{ mod } 3}$ here. But it seems to still be possible to choose a larger $b$ and then keep the $2 \text{ mod } 3$ primes through Chinese Remainder Theorem.

I ran some heuristics in python for $f(n) = n^3 - 2$, and it seems that $2 \text{ mod } 3$ is the only arithmetic progression $a \text{ mod } b$ with $(a, b)$ = 1 that is contained in $\mathcal{P}(n^3 - 2)$, except of course for the ones it contains -- like $2 \text{ mod } 9$. This is consistent with what you're suggesting, but I'm not sure how you would prove that there are no other "primitive" arithmetic progressions contained in $\mathcal{P}(n^3 - 2)$

There is some fairly advanced algebraic number theory behind this problem. If I remember correctly, what you want works for all quadratics, but fails in general for higher degrees. The factorization of $f$ mod $p$ is related to the splitting of the prime $p$ in the field generated by a zero of $f$, and that gets you into deep water.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev%27s_density_theorem will give you some idea of what you are up against.

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3562472/split-primes-in-cubic-field and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36260/finding-out-how-primes-split-in-a-particular-cubic-extension

Maybe the best is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80265/splitting-of-primes-in-an-s-3-extension

see also http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hudson_Williams_1991.pdf    The $n^3 - 2$  bit is by Gauss, top of journal page 134. Table 1 on the same page gives numerous related results, including $n^3 - 3$ by Jacobi.  There is a similar paper on (form) class number 4  by Williams and Liu, Tamkang J. 1994;  highlights  include $n^4 + 3, n^4 + 7, n^4 - 2, n^4 - 5$
